# Zipping excel spreadsheet in memory file

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to zip an excel spreadsheet created by openpyxl along with other files as per code below however i receive the following error, any help

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cprequest.py", line 670, in
>   respond
>       response.body = self.handler()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 217, in
>   **call**
>       self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy_cpdispatch.py", line 60, in
>   **call**
>       return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "example.py", line 2282, in RPC_submit
>       wb.save(iostream4)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line
>   345, in save
>       save_workbook(self, filename)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in
>   save_workbook
>       writer.save(filename)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 248, in
>   save
>       self.write_data()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 81, in
>   write_data
>       self._write_worksheets()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 211, in
>   _write_worksheets
>       self._write_comment(ws)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 181, in
>   _write_comment
>       vml = fromstring(self.workbook.vba_archive.read(ws.legacy_drawing))
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

**Code:**

```
file_name4 = 'SP' + kwargs['sp'] + '-'+ kwargs['WO'] + ' ' + kwargs['site'] + 'TE - ' + 'Asset Distribution' +'.xlsx'
file_path = path + "\\" + file_name4
wb.save(file_path)

iostream4 = StringIO.StringIO()
wb.save(iostream4)

zip_output = StringIO.StringIO()
file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_output, "w")

file.writestr(file_name0, iostream.getvalue())

file.writestr(file_name4, iostream4.getvalue())

file.close()

cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/zip'
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = (
 'attachment; filename={fname}.zip'.format(
     fname='SP' + kwargs['sp'] + '-'+ kwargs['WO'] + ' ' + kwargs['site'] + ' - ' + 'Request for PC Documentation'  +'.zip'
 )
 )
return zip_output.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

issue identified here with solution
https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/766/workbook-cannot-saved-twice